# get directions about 50meters out

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a api3 map that generates the pointer in the correct place for a bed and breakfast using

```
var orchards = new google.maps.LatLng(52.512565,-2.7595);
```

I want to add in the "Get directions" and its working ok except that its ending at a slightly different place. The directions are ending at a house about 100meters down the road - not quite where the lat/long for the map are. The postcode for the guest house is SY6 7DQ but the directions end at SY6 7DG

How can I get the directions to end in the right place.

You can see what I mean here : http://www.dev.ee-web.co.uk/orchards/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6&Itemid=106

Here's the function that I am using::

```
 function calcRoute() {
directionsVisible=true;
//  alter print text
document.getElementById('printMe').innerHTML = " Print directions";

// remove marker
marker.setMap(null);     
var start = document.getElementById("startFrom").value;
var end = "52.512565,-2.7595";
var request = {
    origin:start, 
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  }
});
```

}

I tried putting the correct postcode into google maps, and numbers produced still point to the wrong place.

I'd really appreciate any help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the directions are very accurate when you specify a LatLng on the road. My guess is the original result was unsatisfactory because the marker is off the road.

Go to this page and click on the road where you want the directions to end and copy the latLng value from the right. Paste into your `var end = ...` I recommend saving the precision.

https://files.nyu.edu/hc742/public/googlemaps/geocodeUK.html

Comment: Many thanks for your help Heitor. I went to you link, turned on the satellite view and clicked on the house which I could easily see. However, the address still comes up with 3 Woodland... with the slightly wrong postcode. I tried next door - same result. When I put in the more precise numbers I still get the wrong ending point. What's wrong?

Comment: You're right, clicking on any house gives the same address. I think the geocoding isn't that precise at this location. I am trying to help with where the direction line ends when the directions is requested. When I tested, the line ended practically where I clicked to get the LatLng. Are you clicking on the house to get the LatLng? Make sure you click on the road. If it is still not working, I don't have other ideas :(

Comment: Thanks again Heitor. Yes, I was clicking on the road so I guess that's as good as it get. I did explain ti the lady that might be the case. I do appreciate your time so thanks a lot!